# Hi folks, since days ROS wiki is unavailable

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is her any problem, a hack or a complete redesign of the wiki entry? Could you inform users about that and how long the the site is broken?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131256/hi-folks,-since-days-ros-wiki-is-unavailable./) by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-02-19**:
From China: error 503.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-02-19**:
Same problem here (Germany)

**Comment by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) on 2014-02-19**:
Same problem (Poland).

**Comment by [Okke](https://answers.ros.org/users/7721/okke/) on 2014-02-19**:
Same problem here in the Netherlands, while status.ros.org is saying everything is fine. http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/wiki.ros.org

**Comment by [Michael Stoll](https://answers.ros.org/users/12221/michael-stoll/) on 2014-02-19**:
Same problem (Germany) (http://wiki.ros.org works, but any link => 503)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yesterday our hosting partner has added a frontend cache to the ros.org webserver in order to reduce the load on the machine as well as improve the overall response time.

Obviously that is generating random problems from either all pages being unavailable for certain user to only some pages are not working. Our hosting partner is working on the issue. Please see http://status.ros.org for any progress.

A list of current mirrors to use in the mean time:

- http://mirror-ap.wiki.ros.org/
- http://mirror-eu.wiki.ros.org/
- http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-02-20**:
The change to the webserver has been rolled back and it should by now work for everyone again.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-20**:
status.ros.org shows no problems, but wiki.ros.org does not point to the wiki but some apache directory with api docs and other stuff.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-20**:
aaaand it seems to be back up

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-02-20**:
It's just a roller coaster over there at OSL today. Sorry, hopefully things will smooth out soon.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not seeing any problem with the wiki at the moment.

You can check the status of the ROS services on http://status.ros.org/ . It looks like they were having some stability problems yesterday.

**EDIT** Poking a little more, it looks like the core wiki page is fine, but many other pages on the wiki are having problems. This looks a bit like there are some pages in a cache somewhere, and anything that isn't in the cache returns an error.

**EDIT** Most of the ROS team is asleep right now. I wouldn't expect a resolution on this for another 6-8 hours (around  8pm UTC). I suggest you use the mirrors linked by @IsaccSaito until then.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to paste an image so I post here although this isn't an answer.

Today I and collaborators have been seeing "Page Unavailable" sign on wiki.ros.org from multiple different locations.

[image: image description]

I just posted the list of the mirrors [on our website](http://opensource-robotics.tokyo.jp/?p=302&lang=en) (out of ros.org since I can't reach the list of mirrors on ROS wiki).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My location: Netherlands. wiki.ros.org main page is online, but all other pages are not. e.g. wiki.ros.org works, but wiki.ros.org/gmapping throws the not found error.

You can always use a mirror.
Using the uni freiburg mirror, I can still look at the information.
ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/

---

Originally posted by [robertjacobs](https://answers.ros.org/users/9016/robertjacobs/) with karma: 21 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1